# DocumentListener slows down Document.setCharacterAttributes method?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, documentlistener

this is my first question in this site, though is not the first time I enter to clear my doubts, awesome webpage. :)

I'm writing a java program that highlights code in a JTextPane and I'm changing the way highlights are done. I'm using a JTabbedPane to let the user edit more than one file at the same time and I used to perform document highlights using a Timer, now I've built a highlight queue that runs in a separate thread and implemented a DocumentListener that queues the documents as changes take place.

But I have a really big problem, if I add the document via DocumentListener, the Highlight process takes a really long time while if I add it in the main class by getting the document directly from the JTextPane, it takes just a few milliseconds.
I've performed multiple benchmarks in my code and found out that what takes so much time to be performed when the document is added from the DocumentListener is the method Document.setCharacterAttributes().

Here is the method that adds documents via DocumentListener:

```
// eventType: 0 - insertUpdate / 1- removeUpdate
private void queueChange(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e, int eventType){
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) e.getDocument();
    int changeLength = e.getLength();
    int changeOffset = e.getOffset();
    int length = doc.getLength();
    String title = (String) doc.getProperty("title");

    String text;
    try {
        text = doc.getText(0, length);

        if (changeLength != 1) {
            Element element = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
            int startLn = element.getElement(element.getElementIndex(changeOffset)).getStartOffset();
            int endLn = element.getElement(element.getElementIndex(changeOffset + changeLength)).getEndOffset() - 1;

            Engine.addDocument(doc, startLn, endLn, title, text);
        } else {
            if(eventType == 1){
                changeOffset = changeOffset - changeLength;
            }
            int startLn = text.lastIndexOf("\n", changeOffset) + 1;
            int endLn = text.indexOf("\n", changeOffset);

            if (endLn < 0) {
                if (length != startLn) {
                    endLn = length;

                    Engine.addDocument(doc, startLn, endLn, title, text);
                }
            } else if (startLn != endLn && startLn < endLn) {
                Engine.addDocument(doc, startLn, endLn, title, text);
            }
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Engine.crashEngine();
    }
}
```

If I add a document with 2k lines with this method, it takes ~1900 ms to highlight the whole document, while if I add the document to the highlight queue by using a caret listening method it takes ~500 ms.

Here's a part of the caret listening method that is used to highlight whole documents when they're loaded:

```
if (loadFile == true) {
    isKey = false;
    doc = edit[currentTab].Editor.getStyledDocument();
    try {
        Highlight.addDocument(doc, 0, doc.getLength(),
                Scripts.getTitleAt(currentTab), doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    loadFile = false;
}
```

Note: the Highlight/Engine.addDocument() method has five parameters: (StyledDocument doc,int start, int end, String tabTitle, String docText). Start and end both indicate the region where highlighting is needed.

I will appreciate any help related to this problem cause I've been trying to solve it for a few days and I can't find anything similar on the Internet. :(

Btw, does anyone know the actual difference between Document.setCharacterAttributes and Document.setParagraphAttributes? :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some kind of recursion in your code that is causing the problem. With the DocumentEvent you should only worry about additions and removals. You don't need to worry about changes since those are attribute changes.

Maybe you add some text which schedules the highlighting, but then when you change the attributes of the text you schedule another highllighting task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've ignored the changedUpdate method because the user has no access to text attributes, so there's nothing to be done when that method fires.
Highlights are only queued when insertUpdate or removeUpdate is fired and the highlight method I use highlights the text by setting the character attributes of a portion of the Document, so the method is not inserting more text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a flag indicating whether it's user changes or your API changes. In the beginning of the Engine.addDocument() set the flag to API state and reset it back after changes are done.
In your listener check the flag and skip changes from API.
You wrote " *I use highlights the text by setting the character attributes of a portion of the Document, so the method is not inserting more text*". I'm not sure it doesn't insert text. E.g. you have "it's a bold text piece" then you select the "bold" and change attributes to bold. Original element is separated and 3 new elements appear. I didn't test it but it might call insertUpdate() and removeUpdate()

does anyone know the actual difference between Document.setCharacterAttributes and Document.setParagraphAttributes?
There are paragraph and char attributes. Char attributes are font size, family, style, colors. Paragraph attributes are alignment, indentation, line spacing.
Actually paragraphs are char elements' parents.

Comment: I've just tested and while highlights are being performed insertUpdate() and removeUpdate() are never called.
My guess is that due to the fact that highlights are performed by setting attributes to the text, the document has to notify the document listener every time I call Doc.setCharacterAttributes(), and that seems to be time consuming.
I've tried removing the doc listener before performing the highlight but since the source of the document is the document listener, when I remove the DocListener, changes done to that document are not updated.